# iOS - Why is my UIImageView moving?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Here is my function for which I draw a metronome image within my iOS program. 
When I load it, the metronome image is loaded, but "flies" down from the top left of the screen to the desired position. This is not the behavior I wanted - I simply want the image to appear at the desired position. Could someone enlighten me why this happens, and how to fix it? 
Many thanks in advance.

Pier.

```
- (void) drawMetronomeForBeat: (int) beatNumber withNumberOfBeats:(int) noBeats
{

// remove any previous instances first
if (metronomeImageView) 
{
    [metronomeImageView removeFromSuperview];
}

NSString * imageName = @"metronome";
NSString * noBeatsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", noBeats];
NSString * beatNumberStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", beatNumber];
imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:noBeatsStr]; 
imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"b"]; 
imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:beatNumberStr]; 

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed: imageName];
UIImageView * symbolImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 

[symbolImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(410.0f, 215.0f, symbolImageView.frame.size.width, symbolImageView.frame.size.height)];
metronomeImageView = symbolImageView; 
[self.view addSubview:symbolImageView];
}
```

Comment: Try removing the if statement (with its body), and replace the last line with `[self.view addSubview: metronomeImageView];`

Comment: Doesn't work... I realized that if I draw an image directly in the view code none of this happens. Thanks though...

Comment: What if you first add the subview and then set the frame?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
[symbolImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(410.0f, 215.0f, symbolImageView.frame.size.width, symbolImageView.frame.size.height)];
```

with

```
[symbolImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(410.0f, 215.0f, 22, 22)];  //Change 22, 22 according to size that you need.
```

The image view will become larger or smaller according to the size of "real image" you are displaying. So it will move some where so that `imageview` will stay center aligned.

**EDIT:**

I think you are setting different frame for symbolImageView.

Try this

```
symbolImageView.frame = metronomeImageView.frame;
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. thanks though. The same thing happens, just that the image is of a different size.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Controller to display the images. I restructured my code so that the images are always "drawn" in the drawRect of the view code, like this..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{  

if (metronomeImage)
{
    [metronomeImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(410.0f, 215.0f, metronomeImage.size.width, metronomeImage.size.height)];
}
}
```

This works with no problems - note that I just used drawInRect and just UIImage instead of setFrame and UIImageView. I suppose I'll just follow the convention that anything graphical should be done in the view code, and not the controller.